# Textarea input from HTML is cut off

Tags: php, html, forms, text

I have made a form using a textarea tag which then truncates the text into a file, but the input is cut off after a certain amount of characters and sometimes after a closing unordered list tag. What could be the cause?

The form:

```
<form name='input' method='post' action=''>
<textarea cols=75 rows=17 name='desc'></textarea>
</form>
```

Here's how I insert the text (stored in the $desc variable) into the file:

```
$file->fileTruncate($parent2."/projectfiles/".$data[ID]."/description.html", $desc);
```

Some of my fileHandle class, accessed by the $file object:

```
function fileTruncate($path, $write){

    if(file_exists($path)){

        $this->fp = fopen($path, 'w');

        fwrite($this->fp, $write);

        fclose($this->fp);

        return true;

    }else{

        return false;

    }

}
```

Here's how I display the text, stored in the $desc_contents variable ($file->fileContents basically gets the contents of the given file, "all" means it gets the entire file):

```
    $file = new fileHandle;

echo "<div id='project_description' style='overflow:scroll;'>";

echo "<div id='project_description_text'>";

echo "<br/>".$desc_contents = $file->fileContents("projectfiles/$projectid/description.html", "all");

echo "</div>";

echo "</div>";
```

Here's an example of the text which has been cut off:

## XaocRPG

### Current Features:

Players can gain experience and level up when fighting creatures! 
 Check your stats or another players! (Requires permission: XaocRPG.Commands.Info.Others) 
 Set the experience of entities with /setentexp! 
 Reset all players or just one as an admin! /xrpg reset!

### Planned Features

- Leveling for skills and abilities to replace such plugins as McMMO/MoxieSkills!
- Full Admin Command Set!
- Abilities that can be learned by leveling skills!
- Full permission support.
- Multiworld support.
- Economy Support. (SkEconomy and Vault)
- Suggestions? I\'m open to them!

*Some other text*

*More invisible text*

The italic text should be visible and in the file, but isn't. I checked whether or not it is actually truncated to the file, but it isn't, therefore there's no error with the actual displaying of the text.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: are you using a rich text editor like TinyMCE?

Comment: Nope, but I'll check it out @ÖzkanÖZLÜ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have dumped the text that is arriving to the write function? Is complete?

Comment: Yes, the text that is passed to the write function is complete.

Comment: Try to use htmlentities to convert the text before write and then html_entity_decode after read. Or use a Wyswyg editor as suggested above.

Comment: Thanks, it turns out that the problem was with greater and less than signs, htmlstriptags($string) was stripping all text after a less than sign. I fixed it by converting them to a different piece of text and then changing them back when displaying.

Comment: Great, can you upvote me and close the question? 
Thank you very much